# how to pass data to modal using bootsrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to figure out how to pass a variable to a model. For example, I have a table that have lists of student. I want to click one of them and have a modal popup that is matching that student. So I obviously need to pass some how the id in the table to the model. This is all in Asp.net using razor. And then after having that model popup I would like to edit and resubmit which then would refresh the table. Perhaps even have a success message. I am using the bootstrap so I was thinking of using the alert to say Successfully Updated! or something.
here is the code. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
<body>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>

    <div class="box-content">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>DNIS </th>
                    <th>Created by</th>
                    <th>Created Date</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.service_name)</td>
                        <td class="center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dnis)</td>
                        <td class="center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created_by) </td>
                        <td class="center"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date_time)</td>

                        <td class="center">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="~/Service/AssignSkillGroup/@item.service_name">
                                Add/Del SkillGroup
                            </a>

                            <a class="btn btn-info" href="~/Service/Edit/@item.service_name">
                                <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>
                                Edit
                            </a>

                            <a  class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.service_name" data-target="#myModal" >
                                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                                Delete                          
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                  
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <span class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="height: 175px">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure to want to delete this service ? </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>If you delete the service, Wrap-up codes will not appear for this service</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Service/Delete/">
                    Delete
                    <a><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button> </a>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your modal like the following

```
<span class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="height: 175px">

       <!-- Modal content-->
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" onclick="Close()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure to want to delete this service ? </h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
               <p>If you delete the service, Wrap-up codes will not appear for this service</p>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
               <a class="btn btn-default" id="del" >
                   Yes
               </a>
               <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="Close()">
                   No
               </a>
           </div>
       </div>
</span>
```

The add the following script and call those methods through your delete button and pass the id to the script function.

```
<script>
   function deleteFunction(id) {
       $('#myModal').show();
       var a = document.getElementById('del');
       a.href = "/Service/Delete/" + id;
   }
   function Close()
   {
       $('#myModal').hide();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Mum umer for your time. Your solution is working (y)

Answer (score 2):

You can use bootstrap dialog event to achieve what you want :

```
//triggered when modal is about to be shown
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

  //get id attribute of the clicked element (delete button)
  var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  // do what you want with the id ..
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i need to use data-id="@item.service_name"
in modal where i am calling another method of service controller
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/Service/Delete/">